# Java ResultSet cast to array of my Class type

Tags: java, sql

I am rephrasing my question as apparently some have been offended unintentionally ( I am a Java newbie):(

I am connecting to a DB2 db - The ResultSet contains the first 10 rows from the  table V_LVCS.

I wish to accomplish this !

```
while (rs.next())
{ keys[i] = new V_LVCS();
   keys[i] = this_Row_Object;
}
```

I am after an array of V_LVCS objects. Currently I am converting each data row to V_LVCS object as shown below but I assume there is a better faster way to do this.

```
 public class V_LVCS {



    public String SERIAL;
        public String TRANSFORMERID;
        public String LVT;

        public V_LVCS() {

        }

        public V_LVCS(String Serial, String Transformerid, String lvt) {
            this.SERIAL = Serial;
            this.TRANSFORMERID = Transformerid;
            this.LVT = lvt;
        }

        public V_LVCS[] getAllV_LVC() {
            try {
                Connection conn = getAMMDBConnection();

                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                ResultSet rs;
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM V_LVC FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY");
                rs.last();
                int numRows = rs.getRow();
                V_LVCS[] keys = new V_LVCS[numRows];
                rs.beforeFirst();
                int i = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {


keys[i] = new V_LVCS();
                    keys[i].SERIAL = (rs.getString("SERIAL") == null) ? "" : rs.getString("SERIAL");
                    keys[i].LVT = (rs.getString("LVT") == null) ? "" : rs.getString("LVT");
                    keys[i].TRANSFORMERID = (rs.getString("TRANSFORMERID") == null) ? "" : rs.getString("TRANSFORMERID");
                    ++i;
                }
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("stop!");
                return keys;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                // System.err.println(e.printStackTrace());
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I do really appreciate your thoughts! (and hoped for a few hours of tought before being penalised with -ve scores! )

Comment: This does not have anything to do with [casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: please provide the casting related code which you think can be improved upon.

Comment: you haven't pointed out where your issue is or what exception/problem you are encountering.  this means that anyone trying to help has to do a lot more research and guessing.

Comment: Jesper, Arham and Martin - I read again my question and see your point(s). I have rephrase the question now. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 5):

You just need to change your loop to call the constructor instead of trying to assign to fields:

```
while ( rs.next() ) {           
    String serial = ( rs.getString("SERIAL") == null)?"":rs.getString("SERIAL") ; 
    String lvt = ( rs.getString("LVT") == null)?"":rs.getString("LVT");
    String id = ( rs.getString("TRANSFORMERID") == null)?"":rs.getString("TRANSFORMERID") ;
    keys[i] = new V_LVCS(serial, id, lvt);
    ++i;
}
```

Note, in particular, that this line:

```
V_LVCS [] keys = new V_LVCS[numRows];
```

creates an array of references to `V_LVCS`, *all of which are* `null`. You need to assign something to each element before you can dereference that element.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I have rephrased my question if you are interested in answering.

Comment: @AllTvRepairs - I don't believe that the code you posted would execute successfully (efficiently or not). Inside the loop, you are assigning to `keys[i].SERIAL`, etc. However, you never assigning an object to `keys[i]`, so trying to access `keys[i].SERIAL` should generate a NullPointerException. Either the code you posted is not the code you are running, or else you are getting NPEs from that code. My answer was addressing the latter (which is what I assumed was your problem). Is it?

Comment: Hi Ted, Actually I have inserted keys[i] = new V_LVCS(); before assigning the attibutes of each object.